# How can I set the heap size of spray-can in Sbt's Build.scala?

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin, spray

I've got a running sbt project that can start my server using re-start. The setup was done using the [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin).

Now I noticed that the server process runs with a heap of 128M which is a little short. I know how to configure the heap size for the sbt process, but apparently spray is running a different jvm.

How do I configure a larger heap for spray-can in this kind of setup?

### Details

I've configured my sbt like I answered here: [How to specify JVM maximum heap size "-Xmx" for running an application with "run" action in SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run/14561346#14561346)

BUT when I look at the running processes with jconsole I can see that the server process is running in a different jvm:

[image: jconsole shows different process for server next to sbt-launch.jar]

And I can see that this process has a heap of only 128M instead of the 3.5G I configured in .sbtconfig.

[image: jconsole shows this process has only 128M memory]

Comment: Maybe one of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868863/how-to-specify-jvm-maximum-heap-size-xmx-for-running-an-application-with-run

Comment: thanks @jcern I looked at those, but they modify the sbt jvm; not the jetty jvm.

Comment: are you sure that http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870572/1408096, or http://stackoverflow.com/a/7430656/1408096 won't help? nothing else is coming to my mind ...

Comment: I didn't fix it with those answers (possibly bad reading skills on my part). See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to fix this by [setting the javaOptions for forked JVMs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking#forked-jvm-options)

```
object BuildSettings {
   ....
   val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
     ....
     javaOptions += "-Xmx1G"
     ....
  )
}
```

If you want to be more particular about different processes you can use something like

```
javaOptions in run +="-Xmx1G"
```

But I haven't found which value you should pass to `in` yet.