# How to increase stack size when compiling a play scala project with uncaught exception during compilation: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, playframework

When compiling play2.1 scala project using `eclipse`, I got the error as

> [error] uncaught exception during compilation:java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> [error] (compile:compile)java.lang.StackOverflowError

I tried to configure the compiler in `application.conf` by adding this line:

> jvm.memory=-Xmx5g -Xms5g -Xss8192M

(my program also needs a lot of heap space, so I also added xmx and xms)

but it does not work..

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Really, 8 GIGABYTES of stack size for a Play! app? So you have something like a terabyte of memory available?

Comment: No, I only have 64G memory. I used the 8g for testing, because I was so annoyed by the stack overflow problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange that you get a StackOverflow. It does seem like a bug. However, if it is really the case that you don't have enough stack space, modifying the application.conf won't help you. Those settings control the runtime parameters of your application, whereas your problem is at compilation.

This SO answer shows how to tweak JVM parameters for SBT:
[Out of Memory Error Using SBT When Executing Lift Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751936/out-of-memory-error-using-sbt-when-executing-lift-project)

In your case you would modify the play file in your play distribution folder and add your stack-specific option in there (the play utility is just a customized sbt version).

Answer (score 2):

Your exception is probably due to a bug in the compiler, not insufficient stack size.

Answer (score 1):

```
[error] uncaught exception during compilation:java.lang.StackOverflowError

[error] (compile:compile)java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

They look like they come from a bug in your code. Double check for problems there. Usual SBT problems are or `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`, in which case use @Marius Danila's answer to solve the problem.

Best thing to do is to unit test your method. Play uses `JUnit` or `Selenium` for that. Have a look [here](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/test) and double check your logic with unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

The thing now works, when I shift everything back to older versions: scala 2.9.1 or 2.9.2 all works fine, no stack overflow in compilation time; play version is 2.0.4.